# VS 2017 class library project includes App.Config when "Do not copy" selected for "Copy to Output Directory"

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Noticed that Visual Studio 2017 includes `{ClassProjectName}.DLL.Config` file if the class library has an `App.Config` and `"Copy to Output Directory"` is set to `"Do not copy"`. In VS2015 this setting would not copy the .config file

How to move to VS2015 way of publish

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your publish profile (.pubxml file in "My Project\PublishProfiles"), inside the existing  element:

```
<ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>bin\*.dll.config</ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>
```